# Passing parameters after calling stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following UDF:

```
create function fn_name
  (@first varchar(50),
   @middle  varchar(50),
   @last  Varchar(50))
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
   return 
      case
         when @middle is null then @first+' '+@Last
         when Len(@middle)=0   then @first+' '+@Last
         else @first+' '+@middle+' '+@Last
      end
 end
```

I am thinking of creating a stored procedure for the above function but in such a way that I am passing in the parameters one by one after calling the stored procedure. Is it possible in SQL Server? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean "pass in the parameters one by one"?  Can you edit the question and provide a sketch of what you want the calls to look like?

Comment: like in the above function, if there is no middle name, it wont execute. So i want to turn this into a stored proc but want to pass each of those parameters one by one after i have invoked the Proc.

Comment: You can't use `RETURNS` in a procedure to specify a different data type. `RETURN` is for integer values only, and it should be reserved for status/error codes. If you want a single value returned, use an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really want to call the stored procedure multiple times for each parameter.  That is a nightmare, because you have to save state between the calls.  Instead, use optional parameters:

```
 create procedure usp_name (
    @first varchar(50) = '',
    @middle varchar(50) = '',
    @last varchar(50) = '',
    @name varchar(100) output
 )  
 as
 begin
      select @name = (case when @middle is null then @first+' '+@Last
                           when Len(@middle)=0   then @first+' '+@Last
                           else @first+' '+@middle+' '+@Last
                      end);
 end;  -- usp_name
```

Now, all three parameters are optional.  If you invoke it thus:

```
declare @name varchar(100);
exec @name = @name output;
```

Then it will return `''`.  If you call:

```
declare @name varchar(100);
exec @first = 'Gordon', @last = 'Linoff', @name = @name output;
```

Then you will get `'Gordon Linoff'`.

Not all parameters need be optional as in this example.  They become optional when you specify a default value.

Comment: Except `returns varchar()` does not parse, nor does the body.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Fixed.  (Another case, btw, where I actually tested it and copied the wrong version back over.)

Comment: Did you try executing it? `Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_name, Line 9
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Gordon Linoff' to data type int.` You still can't return a string.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . No, I was using SQL Fiddle (I'm on a Mac right now) and it doesn't support execution as well as definition.  This is another case where `return` with a type other than an int causes an execution failure but not a compile failure.  Has this been recorded as bug with Microsoft?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean about SQLfiddle - I'm on a Mac and I was able to [create the procedure, execute it, and get the same error message I reported above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bcfd0/1). As for the "bug" I think it's similar to a deferred name resolution error - in all honesty I expected the `return` statement to halt execution of the procedure.

Comment: I suppose it parses because you could have valid executions (e.g. [this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bcfd0/6)). SQL Server isn't going to expand that `CASE` expression and determine that there isn't a possible set of parameters that could end up with an `int` being returned.

Comment: I'd change this whole `CASE` with `@first + COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(@middle, ''), '') + ' ' + @last`. Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ec5c/1)